# Deployment a web-site on IIS from another program

Tags: iis, deployment

I developed a web-site on ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 platform. And additional I have 2 win services. My task is to build install package. I decided that Visual Studio install projects are not met my requirements. I design my own installer for this project, because I need to resolve many question and problem in install process. My problem: I need to deploy web-site into IIS, but I don't know how to do it easy. I found Microsoft tool as Web Deployment Tool, but I didn't find   any documentation. And must I include this tool into my installer for deployment at destination customer? Another side I found SDC Tasks Library and it looks like a solution for me. But I saw many topics where people had problems and because the project was dead anybody couldn't help them. I know it is a long story... My question: how can I deploy the web-site from another program (I know that IIS versions have some differences and it is another headache), set a virtual directory, application pool (very important), a type of authentification and so forth ???
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Wix for installers.

This article seems to cover what you want:
[Automating Web deployment on IIS with WIX.](http://ranjithk.com/2009/12/17/automating-web-deployment-using-windows-installer-xml-wix/)